# Groovy each new tr after 4 td

Tags: grails, groovy, each, gsp

I'm working on `<g:each>` in view. I got an `array with size = 6`. I'd like to create a table with 4 td of each tr.
For example: I make loop in array `with size = 6`

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what about groovys `collate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `status` of `g:each` to conditionally start a new row after 4 td:

```
  <tr>
  <g:each var="it" status="i" in="${ar}">
      <g:if test="${ i > 0 && i % 4 == 0 }"></tr><tr></g:if>
      <td>${it}</td>
  </g:each>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the solution given by user @user2472199 will work but you can write it more cleanly by making use of Groovy's [collate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate(int)) method in this way:

```
<g:each var="trElement" in="${ar.collate(4)}">
    <tr>
        <g:each var="tdElement" in="${trElement}">
           <td>${tdElement}</td>
        </g:each>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

This will keep the gsp looks clean and also avoids any HTML validation errors in editors.

Comment: Thanks for another solution. I really appreciate it, BTW.